# run a command if a string is present in a file

Tags: files

I have a file with the string "TEST" in it(without quotes) How can I run a command to check if that string is in that file and output a differentg result depending on if the string is in the file

Answer (score 2):

One common way is to use the exit status of a `grep` command

```
grep -qF TEST file && <command>
```

Ex. given

```
$ cat > somefile
This file contains TEST string
$ cat > otherfile
This file doesn't contain the string
```

then

```
$ grep -qF TEST somefile && echo "Do something"
Do something
$ grep -qF TEST otherfile && echo "Do something"
$
```

Comment: How would you make this one command I am even more confused now

Comment: @9291Sam if you want a more specific answer, please make your question more specific

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out

```
 if grep -q "$STRING" "$FILENAME"; 
 then echo "Yes" ;
 else echo "No" ; 
 fi
```

Worked for me

Comment: Note that this will treat `$STRING` as a *basic regular expression* pattern - which may give unexpected results if it contains special characters such as `.`